# Is there a way to provide an attribute to all models in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Thymeleaf dropped template expressions like `#session`, `#httpServletRequest` etc. in Version 3.1 (https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf31whatsnew.html).

We used those a lot in relatively large applications. I wrote an interceptor to populate those attributes at every request since I don't want to add them in every Controller needed (like described in the migration guide).

Does anybody know a better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that `@ControllerAdvice` can be used in this case (see https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc).

Classes annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`, can have methods annotated with `@ModelAttribute` to populate attributes over *multiple* Controllers (all of them if not specified otherwise).

In my case:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CommonDataAdvice {
     @Autowired
     private HttpServletRequest request;

     @ModelAttribute("request")
     public HttpServletRequest populateRequest(){
           return request;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is already the best method to populate attributes at each request, compared to the earlier methods defined in the [Spring framework documentations.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html)